# Bidrectional @OneToMany relation with a composite key

Tags: jpa

I have been trying to create a bidirectional @OneToMany relation with composite keys but some pieces are missing or wrong.

I have a draft entity which holds a list of sub draft entities.

Here is what I got:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "draft")
@IdClass(Pk.class)
public class Draft {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;
    @Id
    protected Integer rev;  

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "draft")
    List<SubDraft> subDrafts = new ArrayList<SubDraft>();

   // getters / setters omitted 
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "sub_draft")
@IdClass(PK.class)
public class DraftToDoDAO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;
    @Id
    protected Integer rev;  

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "draft_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "draft_rev", referencedColumnName = "rev")     
    })
    protected DraftDAO draft;

   // getters / setters omitted 
}

public class PK implements Serializable {
    protected Long id;
    protected Integer rev;

    public PK() {

    }

    public PK(Long id, Integer rev) {
        this.id = id;
        this.rev = rev;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Integer getRev() {
        return rev;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((rev == null) ? 0 : rev.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        MetaDataDAO other = (MetaDataDAO) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (rev == null) {
            if (other.rev != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!rev.equals(other.rev))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have no problems saving a draft with a list of sub drafts but the relation is not created both ways.

In the sub draft table the SchemaTool (DataNucleus) creates a column named draft_id but it is empty. And I wonder why it is not creating the columns I specified (draft_id, draft_rev) and settles the relation there.

I have search a lot for an answer but just can not get thing to work.

Your help is appreciated! 
Thanks.

EDIT!
Here is the actual persistence code:

```
public Draft create(Draft draft, SubDraft subDraft) {
    EntityManager em = PersistenceHelper.getEntityManager();

    draft.setCreated(Calendar.getInstance());

    // This should do it
    draft.setSubDraft(subDraft);
    subDraft.setDraft(draft);       

    em.persist(draft);
    em.close();

    return draft;
}
```

Comment: and you did set BOTH SIDES of the relation? Just that you post no actual persistence code, or the SQL invoked so asking people to explain why is asking a lot

Comment: and setSubDraft does what? And the SQL invoked is ?

Comment: Okay, the setSubDraft sets the entity of subDraft on Draft to complete the bidirectional relation.

However some where along the line of code this subDraft attribute was nilled and therefore is did not work.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Some where along the line of code this subDraft attribute was nilled and therefore is did not work.